# Cannot find openuri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv

I'm trying to run `bundle install` on my rails project (I've just added Nokogiri) but I ran into a permission error. I installed rbenv (which seems like the right way to go) to get around that problem but now I'm getting

```
Could not find gem 'open-uri (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

I know that `open-uri` is part of ruby though so why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please you post your Gemfile. Maybe you have something like `gem 'open-uri'`  there?

Comment: @basia Thanks, sorry you should have answered the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenURI is part of the Ruby Standard library, it is not a gem. You therefor do not need to include it in your Gemfile, just require it in your code.

```
require 'open-uri'

open('http://stackoverflow.com/')
```